# PHP contact form (spam protection)

Tags: php, contact-form, spam-prevention

Is there a better way (than adding headers such as below) for PHP webforms to be sent directly to inbox and not to junk/spam folders.

```
$to = $email;
$subject = 'subject here';
$headers = "From: "."emailaddress"."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r\n";
```

Thank you!

PS. I have access to the Mail Server and Domain(DNS).

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It doesn't seem to make much sense. Ah, I think I start to understand. When sending email, your emails are filtered out by the spam filter of the receiver, and you want to prevent that. It's got nothing to do with PHP webforms.

Comment: if mail gets sent into SPAM folder, depends on: SMTP Server IP Range (no private IPs), sending address -> Mailserver Domain Name, DNS (MX) Setup of the Sending Domain, content keyword filtering, etc. every receiving Mailserver can make up its own rules.

Comment: Do you control your mailserver and domain (DNS)?

Comment: Yes I have access to the mailserver and DNS.

Comment: Make sure you have reverse DNS set up. Have a clean IP. Mail servers usually have their own rules.

Comment: Do not send crap content - that would help

Comment: You also can set SPF record in your DNS.